Configuration of Python-NEAT algorithm
I am using the NEAT algorithm to optimize traffic signal timings based on inputs like queue lengths from four directions at an intersection. The goal is to generate optimal signal timings as output. However, I’ve run into persistent issues with activation functions in my implementation.
I’m using Python-NEAT for my traffic signal optimization, where:
Inputs: Queue lengths from four directions of the intersection.
Outputs: Signal timings for each direction.

Here is a description of problems I’ve encountered with different activation functions:
ReLU: Keeps increasing the output values to extremely large numbers which then became impracticable to run.
Sigmoid: Although it gives values from zero to 1, I scaled it up by multiplying it by 10 but the problem is that it gets stuck at 1 for all outputs, constantly giving [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] regardless of input values.
tanh: Same problem as sigmoid.
sin: Same problem as sigmoid.
Softplus: Outputs a constant value of 12 for all signal timings.
I initially thought that running the algorithm through multiple generations might solve the problem. So, I left it running overnight with a function like Sigmoid, only to wake up and find that the fitness value had plunged to negative billions.
I am evaluating my fitness value as below:
if queue_length_north_avg > 15:
                fitness_N += queue_length_north_avg + ((queue_length_north_avg - 15) ** 2)
            else:
                fitness_N += queue_length_north_avg

Then adding the fitness from all direction and subtracting it from the genome.fitness like below:
        fitness = fitness_N + fitness_S + fitness_E + fitness_W / 4
        genome.fitness -= fitness

My question is what could be causing these issues with the activation functions in my NEAT implementation, and how can I configure the algorithm to produce more stable outputs that can lead to meaningful optimization of the signal timings?
and is it possible to input for different fitness for all four directions? and will it help?
My configuration file is the following:
*
[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 1
pop_size              = 30
reset_on_extinction   = False

[DefaultGenome]
#compatibility_weight_coefficient = 1.0
activation_default      = softplus
activation_mutate_rate  = 0.0
activation_options      = softplus

aggregation_default     = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.0
aggregation_options     = sum

bias_init_mean          = 0.0
bias_init_stdev         = 1.0
bias_max_value          = 10.0
bias_min_value          = 0.0
bias_mutate_power       = 0.5
bias_mutate_rate        = 0.4
bias_replace_rate       = 0.1

compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.0
compatibility_weight_coefficient   = 1.0

conn_add_prob           = 0.5
conn_delete_prob        = 0.5

enabled_default         = True
enabled_mutate_rate     = 0.01

feed_forward            = True
initial_connection      = full_direct

node_add_prob           = 0.2
node_delete_prob        = 0.2

num_hidden              = 4
num_inputs              = 4
num_outputs             = 4

response_init_mean      = 1.0
response_init_stdev     = 0.1
response_max_value      = 10.0
response_min_value      = 0.0
response_mutate_power   = 0.1
response_mutate_rate    = 0.1
response_replace_rate   = 0.05

weight_init_mean        = 0.0
weight_init_stdev       = 0.5
weight_max_value        = 10
weight_min_value        = 0.0
weight_mutate_power     = 0.5
weight_mutate_rate      = 0.4
weight_replace_rate     = 0.1

[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 3.0

[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation       = 20
species_elitism      = 2

[DefaultReproduction]
elitism            = 2
survival_threshold = 0.3*

